# Preemptive authentication with Zeep and requests

Tags: python, soap, python-requests, soap-client, zeep

I need to talk to a SOAP server which requires "preemptive authentication" (it uses BasicAuth).

I have no idea of how to configure my zeep client to make it behave accordingly.

As it says [here](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html#preemptive), the SoapUI tool can be configured to use "preemptive authentication"

**Can anyone please help me achieve the same?** (either configuring zeep or requests)

Here is my code, which is pretty standard:

```
session = Session()
session.verify = False  # ignore certificate
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd)

transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(wsdl, transport=transport)
# ...
response = client.service.Operation(**params)
```

The above fails authenticating and ends up with an SSL error, which is expected.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you please share stack trace?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I have signed an NDA.. and I do not want to debug. I know what the problem is. I am asking if you know how to authenticate against a SOAP service that requires/adopts "preemptive authorization". I do not know how to config the Zeep SOAP library or the transport medium it uses (i.e. requests by default)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should be able to do this by creating a session and modifying the headers directly. This way, the header will be sent with the original request instead of using the auth behavior of waiting for a challenge.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + <your 64-bit encoded user:pass>
transport = zeep.Transport(session=session)
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=soapURI,transport=transport)
```